# Why does the viewport view not match the render output when I enter Camera View?

Tags: rendering, camera

I've found dozens of people posting the same question, most of whom, have also spent considerable time researching.  Then I posted here and found some nice people willing to have a conversation with me about my setup.  I posted photographs and I uploaded my .blend file and so, if you'll allow, I'd like someone to explain why my render is different from what I see when I press keypad 0.  Isn't that the point of keypad 0?  Is this a bug?  Is it possible to break keypad 0?  How can it be fixed?

If I press keypad 0, why doesn't that view NOT match what the renderer gives me?  (Blender v2.83)

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If you feel your previous question was incorrectly [marked as duplicate](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates), or the linked posts don't adequately address your issue, go back to your previous question and edit by pressing the *Edit* button below, including information of what you have tried, why it failed and how the duplicates don't address your issue. Once edited the question is automatically queued up for review so it can be reopened.

Comment: It seems dozens of people are posting the same question and not getting an answer that explains why their render doesn't match keypad 0.

Comment: Dozens of people are in fact posting the same question over and over, sadly. You were just pointed to one of many one of the many duplicates of a duplicate, both of which contain valid answers. Don't those answer your queries?

Comment: In my original question, someone helped me to understand that I need to pull back the view from Keypad 0 until I can see the camera's frame.  So then I asked a new question, to discover why such a maneuver would be necessary.  I wanted to learn why my keypad 0 isn't connected to an actual view.

Comment: So, I understand why the render is different from what I was viewing.  Now, I'm asking a different question... Why is keypad 0 broken?

Comment: The camera view resumes from whatever zoom level you used the last time you snapped to it

Comment: numpad (not keypad) 0 does not position you exactly at the point where the camera is located.  It only positions you on a line that extends from the camera along it's view angle.  Your position can be anywhere at all along that line.  This is not 'broken'.  This is how it's designed to work.

Comment: @WynnSmith please adjust title to something relevant, now it is not even a question. In comment you wrote you're asking different thing then in previous post, but I see still "why view doesn't match render ... Since you understood the Camera View (numpad-zero) was zoomed ... Does it - Why Camera View keeps previously set zoom in 3Dviewport on shortcut?

Answer (score 4):

Nothing is broken, here, this is an intended design.

Camera view allows you to zoom in or out without permanently moving the camera object so you can close in on details or inspect the scene without exiting camera view.

This allows you to keep your carefully crafted camera position, possibly even animated, while zooming in on a specific detail of your shot as seen exactly from the current camera angle, or perhaps zoom out far enough to select an object that is just out of view, clipped away, select a different camera that is just around the edge, or even an animated object about to enter the frame before it is visible, all of this from the comfort of the current camera view without the inconvenience of not having to leave, nor permanently altering the location of this camera by accident.

You are expected to reset zoom level with  <kbd>Home</kbd> key or *View > Camera > Frame * Camera Bounds* to get a reliable overview of the true camera framing, indicated by the *passepartout* visual guide.

If you are zoomed in then what you seen will obviously not match the whole camera view frame, only an arbitrary cropped portion of it.

This may not be the way other 3D software work, but it has its advantages and disadvantages and it is certainly not broken.

> So, I understand why the render is different from what I was viewing.
> Now, I'm asking a different question... Why is keypad 0 broken?

Only a developer or the original creator will know why, this is not really a question we can answer, nor on topic here. As far as I am concerned it is not broken, it was designed this way, and is quite useful as it is. Going back to other software that works as you expect I find myself frequently ruining by accident established camera points of view that have specific crafted locations.

If you don't like the behavior you can even disable it from the *3D View Properties Shelf* ( <kbd>N</kbd> key) under *View > View Lock > Camera to View*.